# Automatically convert uuids to url safe strings using node-pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I use uuid for just about every ID in my REST backend powered by node and postgres. I also plan to use validate.js to make sure the queries are formatted correctly.

In order to shorten the URLS for my application, I would like to convert all UUIDS used by my backend into URL safe strings when exposed to the REST consumer.

The problem is that, as far as I can tell there is no such setting within node-pg. And node-pg usually returns the query results as JSON objects using either strings or numbers. That makes it hard to autmatically convert them.

I could of course just go through every single rest endpoint and add code that automatically converts all the types where I know a UUID would be. But that would violate DRY and also be a hotbed for bugs.

I also could try to automatically detect strings that look like UUIDs and then just convert them, but that also seams like it may introduce lots of bugs.

One ideal solution would be some sort of custom code injection into node-pg that automatically converts uuids. Or maybe just some pg function I could use to automatically convert the uuids within the pg-queries themselves (although that would be a bit tedious).

Another Ideal solution might be some way to use validate.js to convert the outputs and inputs during the validation. But I don't know how I could do this.

So basically, what would be a good way to autmatically convert uuids in node-pg to url safe (shorter) strings without having to add a bit of code to every single endpoint?

Comment: Why not cast them in SQL? e.g. `$1::uuid` - that would immediately throw an error if the passed value isn't a valid `uuid`

Comment: i'd still need a method to convert them to a uuid first

Comment: Why, just pass it as a string

Comment: yeah, but I want it to fully automatically convert i back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what I want: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types
It lets me set custom converters for each datatype. The input will probably still have to be converted manually